# Nodejs stuck on processing whenever the app is restarted

Tags: node.js

I have a nodejs application running on Linux, as we all know, whenever I restart the nodejs app it will get a new PID, suppose while the nodejs app is running, a client connects to it and running some process and the process status is processing, during that point of time, if the nodejs app restarts(on the server-side), how can we make sure the client connects back to the previous processing state.

What is happening now is, whenever the server restarts, the process stucks in processing forever.

Just direct me to a sample of how this scenario is handled in real life.

Thank You.

Comment: Now 100% sure what you're asking, but you could be talking about the simplest thing like the value of a global variable.  If you set `x = 5` then restart your process, `x` won't necessarily be `5` right away again, unless your process follows the same path of execution and receives the same input that led it to setting it to `5` the previous time.  But more generally speaking, if you need persistent state then store your state in a database, not in a global variable.

Answer (score 0):

If I'm understanding you correctly, then the answer is you can't...

The reason for this is that, when you restart the process the event loop is restarted, meaning any processes that were running or were waiting in the event loop are gone. You are essentially clearing out the event loop when you restart.

I would say though, if you know the process is 'crashing' node then you probably want to look into that process and see why is crashing, place it in a try catch to it wont kill the server.

now with that said ( and without knowing what, processing state really means ) you could set a flag in your DB server for say 'job1' and have a status column of say 'running' when it was kicked off. When the node server restarts it can read Job status for 'running' jobs, if the 'job' is in a 'running' state you can fire off the job again and once complete update the table to 'completed'

This probably not the most efficient way as it's much better to figure out why the process if crashing, but as a fall-back this could work although in a clustered environment this could cause issues because server 1 may fail while server 2 is processing because server 1 does not know what server two is doing. With more details as to the use case, environment etc would probably allow for a better answer

Comment: hi, the process is not crashing. Nodejs is working as a backend for a mobile app frontend, the mobile app is a bill payment app, when a client using the mobile app to perform the bill payment, nodejs will process that payment, while it's processing, IF I restart the node server, that process state showing processing and stays there forever once the node comes back online. What I want is, NodeJs should resume the process once it comes back after a restart. Is this possible?